# Building a simple RESTful API with Mongo and Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm working with a project that recently switched over to Node from Rails, where one of my favorite features was how easy it was to create a simple REST API, like so:

- `localhost:3000/materials/` *Gets a JSON document of all objects
  inside materials*
- `localhost:3000/materials/:id` *Gets a JSON output of the object with
  that id, e.g. /materials/123123 gives me item 123123*
- `localhost:3000/materials/` *Gets a JSON document of all objects
  inside materials*

And so on. I'm using Mongo. Is there a way of doing this in Node, or is there a guide or a package I should install that can do this?

Comment: MongoDB already has a ReST interface, why don't you use it?

Comment: Really? I had no idea! Do you have any good resources I could use to learn about it?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

Comment: Good decision! Yes, it's possible and it's easy. There are so many tutorials covering this subject that I think it's not worth a real answer. Search for 'mongo node.js express rest' - you'll find too much to read it all.

Comment: It might be a bit outdated (not the newest mongo driver) but there you find a [small example](https://github.com/hgoebl/my-slides/tree/master/code-snippets/json-api-mongo)

Answer (score 0):

Check out LoopBack from StrongLoop Suite, it has a built-in RESTful api explorer that interacts with Mongo using the mongodb connector. http://docs.strongloop.com/loopback/#using-the-api-explorer and http://strongloop.com/strongloop-suite/loopback/

For example, you could create the "materials" model with just the following commands:
`slc lb model materials` and then the restful api will get auto-generated for you at localhost:3000/explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Restify, to build RESTful Web Services in Node.js

A good tutorial at: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-27-restify-build-correct-rest-web-services-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/en/index.html) seems like what you want. You can specify routes very simply as follows:

```
app.get('/:collection', function(request, response) {
  // the value of :collection is stored in request.params
  var coll = request.params.collection;
  var search = request.query; // a hash containing the querystring arguments
  // do stuff with request body, query parameters, etc.
  response.send(data); // send the response
});

app.get('/:collection/:item', function(request, response) {
  var coll = request.params.collection;
  var item = request.params.item;
  // do stuff
  res.json(data); // can also send a JSON response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at restgoose. It is a Typescript library that makes simple REST API development super simple.

https://xurei.github.io/restgoose/